# Reading a text file with pandas/numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, text

I need to read the observations from this file and store them per day basis. The daily observations start with a # and below that line are the daily observations. The columns in the observations are 'LVLpTYP', 'ETIME', 'PRESSURE','GPH','TEMP','RH','DPDP','WDIR','WSPD'respectively. I don't want to skip the heading rows containing the #s as they have the timestamps.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o_M_nOSFU4J39Bczs4VfsCONrM-9l5w/view?usp=sharing

I couldn't come up with any solutions which will allow me to do the same.

This way I could read them as the strings but it's not helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

arrays = [np.array(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('INM00043333-data.txt')]
```

The output should be something like this:

time_stamps = [2016 02 06, 2016 03 06...... like this] #list/array containing the time information from the #line i.e., #INM00043333 2016 02 06 00 0000  247 ncdc-gts   116667        927167

and

data = [ ] #the lines between the two #ed lines in a dataframe

So that the index i from the time_stamps array represents the data for the first date and so on. If I pull up a particular date from the time_stamps array it should reflect the corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

This question is extremely vague and needs more detail in order for the question to be answered accurately. This includes clarification on what "proper" storage format of this file, and likely code that you have as an attempt to solve this problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

What stopping you read this file?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(r"D:\Downloads\INM00043333-data.txt", delimiter= '\s+')
print(df)
print(df.columns)
```

output #df

```
      #INM00043333 2016 02 06 00 0000  247 ncdc-gts   116667        927167
0      21 -9999 100100B -9999   234B -9999    31      36...           NaN
1      10 -9999 100000A   79B  230B -9999    38       5...            NaN
2      20 -9999  97800 -9999   234B -9999    25       25...           NaN
3      20 -9999  96400 -9999   250B -9999   110      -9999...         NaN
4      20 -9999  96000 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999        50 ...          NaN
...                                                  ...         ...
90224  30 -9999  -9999   600 -9999 -9999 -9999        55 ...         NaN
90225  30 -9999  -9999   900 -9999 -9999 -9999        55 ...         NaN
90226  30 -9999  -9999  1800 -9999 -9999 -9999        70 ...         NaN
90227  30 -9999  -9999  2100 -9999 -9999 -9999        90 ...         NaN
90228  30 -9999  -9999  2400 -9999 -9999 -9999        85 ...         NaN
```

df # columns

```
Index(['#INM00043333 2016 02 06 00 0000  247 ncdc-gts   116667', '927167'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Here I want to store the data according to the dates where the date information is in the line starting with #.

Comment: I want to read the lines between the # lines and store them separately.

Comment: Pls update same with sample example showing how your expected output should like with question...How u want to modify the data...